# My code does not write anything on the database

Tags: php, sql, database

This is my CODE, id do not know where is the mistake but this code does not create any information on the database.

```
<?php
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $hostname = "localhost";

    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Could not connect to database");

    $selected = mysql_select_db($dbhandle);

        if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])){
            $user = $_POST['user'];
            $pass = $_POST['pass'];

            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username='$user'");
            if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0 ) { //check if there is already an entry for that username
                echo "Username already exists!";
            }else{
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (Username, Password) VALUES ('$user', '$pass')");
                header("location:begin.html");
            }
    }
    mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: **Stop** using depricated `mysql_*` API. use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` with prepared Statements. Check for Errors after executing mysql command

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: @M4R1KU How if OP never check for it

Comment: always check for errors for any query command...

Comment: and you hav'nt selected any schema...

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and are simply assuming that your queries and select call will never fail. Since you're calling select_db wrong, your queries fail, return boolean false, and you propagate that false through the rest of your code. **NEVER** assume success with db operations. Always assume failure, check for failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Could not connect to database");

$selected = mysql_select_db($dbhandle);
```

In above code you are not passing any database name to use, you should pass a database name instead of connection link to mysql_select_db($dbhandle);

like

> $db_selected = mysql_select_db('foo', $link);

For reference 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php

Answer (score 1):

Forget database name here.

change this:

```
$selected = mysql_select_db($dbhandle);
```

With

```
$selected = mysql_select_db($dbname,$dbhandle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi first of all Please use `mysqli` or `PDO` as `mysql` is depreciated and completely removed from `PHP7`.

Now your problem . You are not included `database` name in your `mysql_select_db`. It should be

```
 $selected = mysql_select_db($dbhandle , $databasename) or die(mysql_error($dbhandle));
```

Always remember try to echo error after any query this will solve your problem in many cases